# Launch Attribute Table from Sublayer Menu

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I've added

`layerControlLayerInfos: {
             menu: [{
                  label: 'Query Layer...',
                  iconClass: 'fa fa-search fa-fw',
                  topic: 'queryLayer'
              }, {
                  label: 'Open Attribute Table',
                  topic: 'openTable',
                  iconClass: 'fa fa-table fa-fw'
              }]
            },`

What are the additional steps need to launch a attribute table from a sublayer menu?

How do I subscribe other widgets to the topic defined above?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes table widget doesn't listen for this topic out of the box. It needs an 'invisible' widget to listen for the topic `layerControl/openTable` which builds its table parameters that will define its fields, and other settings and open the table with `attributesContainer/addTable`.

```
widgets: {
    attributesTableMenu: {
        type: 'invisible',
        path: 'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        id: 'attributesTableMenu',
        options: {
            startup: function(){
                topic.subscribe('layerControl/openTable', function(layer){
                    topic.publish('attributesContainer/addTable', {
                        title: layer.subLayer.name,
                        topicID: layer.layer.id + layer.subLayer.id,
                        queryOptions: {
                            queryParameters: {
                                url: layer.layer.url + '/' + layer.subLayer.id,    
                                where: '1=1'
                            }
                    },
                    //other table options 
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is documented at the bottom of the latest CMV docs on this page: http://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/widgets/LayerControl/